# Router to Receive Client-to-LAN and forward to LAN-to-LAN VPN

Tags: router, vpn, lan, cisco-vpn-client

I work as Telecomunications Services provider and I usually connect to customer network by using VPN Softwares like Quidway SVN Client and Cisco Any Connect.

But now, one of our customers does not accept VPN for remote access anymore. Only VPN from LAN to LAN.

What I need to do is: -> To connect my LAN to a LAN which uses Cisco-Pix (specification bellow) Authentication Method Pre-shared key (PSK) Encryption Scheme IKE Diffie-Hellman Group Group 2 Encryption Algorithm 3des-cbc Hashing Algorithm SHA1 Main or Aggressive Mode Main Mode Lifetime (for renegotiation) 28800 seconds Encapsulation (ESP or AH) ESP Encryption Algorithm 3DES Authentication Algorithm SHA1 Perfect Forward Secrecy Disable Lifetime (for renegotiation) 3600 seconds Lifesize in kB (for renegotiation) Not used

-> To allow our enginners to access my LAN (Client to LAN) which is connected to customers network (LAN to LAN). -> I intend also to straightly receive the ISP (200mb/100mb)

Can it be resolved with only one router? Can anybody help me on this?

Tks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging on the internet, I've found the solution for my problems.

[RV042G](http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/routers/csbr/rv0xx/quick_start/guide/RV0xx_QSG_78-19481.pdf)

IPsec
50 IPsec site-to-site tunnels for branch office connectivity
QuickVPN

50 QuickVPN tunnels for remote client access
PPTP

5 PPTP tunnels for remote access

Encryption
Data Encryption Standard (DES), Triple Data Encryption Standard (3DES), and Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) encryption; AES-128, AES-192, AES-256

Authentication
MD5/SHA1 authentication

IPsec NAT traversal
Supported for gateway-to-gateway and client-to-gateway tunnels

Dead peer detection (DPD), IKE, split DNS